# What is the meaning of "from within"?

Tags: meaning, comprehension

I need your help please.

What is the meaning of "**from within**" and when can use it?

For Example, I met the following sentence when I was reading an article :

> A column segment is a column of data from within the rowgroup.

Answer (score 7):

The phrase **from within** is opposite in meaning to **from outside**. In other words, it means **inside**:

> A column segment is a column of data **inside** the rowgroup.

Another example:

> No one can help you, but yourself. So, your personal development can only happen **from within**.